# How to get app_domains attribute array from Facebook API

Tags: php, laravel, facebook-graph-api

Following at the Facebook API docs I'm able to return only 4 attributes from my FB app.

My Code:

```
$user = Auth::user();
try {

$response = $this->facebook->get('/'.$user->facebook_app_id, $user->facebook_access_token);
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
            echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            exit;
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
            echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            exit;
        }

$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();

dd($graphNode);
```

This only returns 4 attributes

[image]

I need it to also return app_domains. Looking at the docs it looks like it should? Is there a way to return the app_domains array from a FB app? [FB app API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/application/)

Comment: I'm not expert on this, but I'd hazard a guess that your token is wrong.

Comment: If my token was wrong, it would return an error. I'm returning 4 attributes from my FB app that are correct.

Comment: The "Permissions" section of the page you linked reads "An app access token can be used to view all fields for an app." To me, that implies that *some* fields can be viewed without an access token. And the fields you've shown look like the sorts of things that might well be public information. But checking the documentation more closely shows that the fields you're seeing are all labelled as "default", and clicking that takes you to [a page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#fields) that seems to indicate that if you want more fields you need to ask for them.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you'll need to use something like this:

```
$response = $this->facebook->get('/'.$user->facebook_app_id,
    ['fields' => 'app_domains'],
    $user->facebook_access_token
);
```